# Backbone localStorage and relations

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, relational-model, backbone-local-storage

I'm having two RelationalModels, Student and School. School has many Students. All the data is to be stored in Backbone.localStorage

I need advice how the following should be done:

- I suppose I need two collections, one for each model, Student and School?
- I'm confused about how to store the data using localStorage. Should each collection store data in its own localStorage?

Answer (score 2):

I understand you are using [Backbone.localStorage](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage) to accomplish local storage with backbone.js.

As I see it, you would need two collections - `SchoolsCollection` and `StudentsCollection`. `SchoolsCollection` would implement the local-storage uplink:

```
var SchoolsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

  localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("schools")

});
```

Within `SchoolsCollection` you would save models of type `SchoolModel`. Instances of `SchoolModel` would carry an attribute named `students`, beeing an instance of `StudentsCollection`.

This would result in the localstorage look something similar like

```
key: schools
value: afe5a7bd,afe5a7bd

key: schools-afe5a7bd
value: {"name":"MIT","students":[{"name":"Joe"}],"id":"afe5a7bd"}

key: schools-afe5a7bd
value: {"name":"Eaton","students":[{"name":"Max"}],"id":"afe5a7bd"}
```

As you can see, `StudentModel` looses its type on serialization. You have to implement `parse()` in `SchoolModel` to complement this effect:

```
var SchoolModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    parse: function(response) {
        return _.extend({}, response, {
            students: new StudentCollection(response.students)
        });
    }
});
```

A single school model gets restored by `parse()` with a custom treatment of it's attribute `students`. A new `StudentsCollection` is beeing created with the array of objects containing key-value-pairs describing each student's model.

Comment: If I don't specify localStorage property in my StudentsCollection as well, I'll get "Error: A "url" property or function must be specified". Also, I don't really understand how the StudentModel get stored this way... If I wanna fetch a collection with all Students in a view, do I have to loop through the Schools students attribute?

Comment: @user1121487 be careful not to use methods like `create()` on the nested collections - this may be the cause of the mentioned error. use methods that don't do unnecessary syncing like `add()`. for accessing your models you might try this for the first school/the first student: `schools.at(0).get('students').at(0)`

Comment: I met the same problem recently and block me for a long time. I think the parse() method should be the keypoint. But not so familiar with Backbone yet, so how to do this? Can you give more hints?